# copy_to_user failing with linux kernel page tables

Tags: c, linux-kernel, page-tables

I'm writing a system call in the Linux Kernel that given a virtual address and an unsigned long pointer, finds the corresponding page table entry and then copies its contents into the unsigned long pointer. Here is the system call:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(readMMU, unsigned long, vaddr, unsigned long*, pte) {
    unsigned long* kernel_pte;
    unsigned char* page_table;
    struct task_struct *pid_task;
    pgd_t *pgd;
    pud_t *pud;
    pmd_t *pmd;
    pte_t *page_te;
    unsigned long n;


    kernel_pte = kmalloc(sizeof(unsigned long), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (copy_from_user(kernel_pte, pte, sizeof(unsigned long)) > 0) {
        printk("Error: copy from user returned more than 0\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //System call implementation in between here
    printk("Getting Task\n");

    pid_task = get_pid_task(find_get_pid(current->pid), PIDTYPE_PID);

    printk("Getting pgd\n");
    pgd = pgd_offset(pid_task->mm, vaddr);

    printk("Getting pud\n");
    pud = pud_offset(pgd, vaddr);

    printk("Getting pmd\n");
    pmd = pmd_offset(pud, vaddr);

    printk("Getting pte\n");
    page_te = pte_offset_kernel(pmd, vaddr);

    *kernel_pte = pte_val(*page_te);

    printk("Can we access pte?: %d\n", access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, pte, sizeof(unsigned long)));
    printk("Can we acces kernel_pte?: %d\n", access_ok(VERIFY_READ, kernel_pte, sizeof(unsigned long)));

    if ((n = copy_to_user(pte, kernel_pte, sizeof pte)) > 0) {
        printk("Error: copy to user returned more than 0\n");
        printk("copy to user failed to copy this many bits: %ld\n", n);
        return -1;
    }

    kfree(kernel_pte);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the test program that's calling the system call:

```
int
main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    unsigned long vaddr;
    unsigned long *pte;
    vaddr = (size_t) malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));



    /* Print a friendly message */
    printf ("Hello from User Space!\n");



    /* Call our new system call */
    syscall (181, vaddr, pte);

    /* Exit the program */
    return 0;
}
```

Currently the call to copy_to_user is failing with a return value of 8 meaning it that it copied none of kernel_pte into pte. I checked pte with access_ok for VERIFY_WRITE and it returns with a 1. However, acces_ok called on kernel_pte with VERIFY_READ returns with a 0. I'm not sure if that is what is causing copy_to_user to fail, but looking at the source code for copy_to_user it looks like it only checks the user pointer again. So I'm at a bit of a loss why the call is failing.

Comment: `access_ok` checks only that address is not a kernel address. For copy_to_user success, address should belongs to the address space of current process. You need to check user-space program, which pass address to the syscall.

Comment: It seems to me like the address space of the `pte` should be correct because it was passed into the system call from the test program.

Comment: You doesn't initialize `pte` in the test program. Or you should declare it `unsigned long` and pass address of it to the syscall,

Comment: That was it, thanks! Silly for me to overlook that.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't initialize `pte` in the test program. Or you should declare it `unsigned long` and pass address of it to the syscall,
                    – Tsyvarev